# Using git with Doxygen FILE_VERSION_FILTER

Tags: git, version-control, doxygen

What command would be used with git for the doxygen `FILE_VERSION_FILTER`? The output would preferably be the number of times that file as been revised in the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was looking more for a git command that accepts a file name and outputs how many times that file has been included in a commit.

For a file, you can use one of the `git log` commands in "[List all commits for a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3701404/6309)":

```
git log --follow --name-only --format='%H' -- afile | wc
```

Another option, in "[How to get the git commit count?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/677436/6309)" (`git rev-list HEAD --count`) would apply to the all repo, not one single file.
It was introduced in [commit f69c501, Git 1.7.2-rc1, Jun 2010](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f69c501832ecd6880602c55565508e70c3a013d5).
Combined with a `-- afile`, it can work too. Note the option was only offically documented in [commit 75d2e5a, Git 2.4.7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/75d2e5a7b038debee406805c9e21a86e7c085789).

---

Original answer, for a all repo:

In Git, the usual command is [`git-describe`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe).

Either:

```
git describe --long --all --abbrev=7
```

Or (if you have put at least one tag)

```
git describe --long --tags --abbrev=7
```

See "[Deriving application build version from `git describe` - how to get a relatively straightforward string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3302090/6309)".

Comment: Is there a way to make git output the number of times that a specific file has been changed? You didn't fully answer my question.

Comment: Git describe does include the number of times a file has changed (since a beach start, or since the last tag)

Comment: I was looking more for a git command that accepts a file name and outputs how many times that file has been included in a commit.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but since I found it looking for the same problem, here's my solution:

```
FILE_VERSION_FILTER    = "git log --format='%H' -1"
```

It will actually just get the git revision for each file and that seems to be the intended use of `FILE_VERSION_FILTER`. If you like, you could use abbreviated revisions by changing format from `'%H'` to `'%h'`.

Answer (score 1):

`git revlist --count` accepts a list of paths after `--` (I don't know if this is a recent feature or if it has always been there).

Since doxygen wants a single command to call using `popen()`, I'm using a small script like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo -n "File version: "
git -C <path_to_git_directory> rev-list HEAD --count -- $1
```

`-C` is necessary if doxygen is not executed in the git directory and requires a recent git version.